# Mechanism for extracting data out of Cassandra for load into relational databases

Tags: mysql, hadoop, cassandra, etl

We use Cassandra as our primary data store for our application that collects a very large amount of data and requires large amount of storage and very fast write throughput.

We plan to extract this data on a periodic basis and load into a relational database (like mySQL). What extraction mechanisms exist that can scale to the tune of hundreds of millions of records daily? Expensive third party ETL tools like Informatica are not an option for us. 
So far my web searches have revealed only Hadoop with Pig or Hive as an option. However being very new to this field, I am not sure how well they would scale and also how much load they would put on the Cassandra cluster itself when running? Are there other options as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at `sqoop`, it has an integration with Cassandra as shown [here](http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise2.0/sqoop/sqoop_help).

This will also scale easily, you need a Hadoop cluster to get `sqoop` working, the way it works is basically:

- Slice your dataset into different partitions.
- Run a Map/Reduce job where each mapper will be responsible for transferring 1 slice.

So the bigger the dataset you wish to export, the higher the number of mappers, which means that if you keep increasing your cluster the throughput will keep increasing. It's all a matter of what resources you have.

As far as the load on the Cassandra cluster, I am not certain since I have not used the Cassandra connector with `sqoop` personally, but if you wish to extract data you will need to put some load on your cluster anyway. You could for example do it once a day at a certain time where the traffic is lowest, so that in case your Cassandra availability drops the impact is minimal.

I'm also thinking that if this is related to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14532230/1332690), you might want to consider exporting to Hive instead of MySQL, in which case `sqoop` works too because it can export to Hive directly. And once it's in Hive you can use the same cluster as used by `sqoop` to run your analytics jobs.

Comment: I took a brief look at squoop (dubbed SQL-to-Hadoop) and it seemed to be a mechanism for getting data from mySQL-like databases into a hadoop FS. My data movement direction is in the opposite direction. Your provided link on Cassandra integration also seems to show it as a mechanism of loading data into Cassandra and not exporting from it. Am I missing something?

Comment: `sqoop` has an import and export mode, I haven't used the Cassandra connector but I would assume it works just the same. I will check more.

Comment: One alternative I was considering is to run the extract jobs from a snapshot copy of the production cassandra interface in case the ETL mechanism puts heavier than acceptable load on the server.

Comment: Using a snapshot sounds like a good idea and you could just create your ETL to read SSTables and load their content afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to extract data out of cassandra other than paying for etl tool. I tried different way like copy command or cql query -- all the methods gives times out irrespective of changing timeout parameter in Cassandra.Yaml. Cassandra experts say you can not query the data without 'where' clause. This is big restriction to me. This may be one of the main reason not to use cassandra at least for me.